# How do I email java files to someone and have javac compile correctly?

Tags: java, junit

I have several class files in a project (residing in the default package).  My teacher needs me to email him the java files only, and these files need to compile on his computer without errors.  To test this out, I copied my class files to another folder and ran javac myself.  I get errors when I try to compile that say `package org.junit does not exist import static or.junit.Assert.*;`  There are other errors as well but I'm assuming they're probably related to that first one.

Most of the class files in my directory are indeed test classes that I'm using to test methods with JUNIT.  What files do I need to include or what changes do I need to make so that anyone could simply use `javac` and compile my `java` files?

Here's a sample of one of my classes:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SetRadiusTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Circle test = new Circle(200, 0, 0);
        test.setRadius(200);
        assertEquals(100, test.getRadius(), 1);

        test.setRadius(50);
        assertEquals(50, test.getRadius(), 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing *you* can do except ensure that you use only classes available in the compilation environment. But you should email a zip file with the complete package hierarchy. Although you appear to have everything in the default package :/

Answer (score 0):

Check the java class path and it will tell you the dependencies you need to compile your application.  running javac at the command line acts differently than when it is automatically compiled by an IDE like eclipse if the class paths do not match.  For commonly used jar files like JUnit your teacher should probably already have it in their environment.  You should only include need to include jar files which are not part of a common configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check a java class path, nor do I know what it would mean to modify it.  Could you give me an example or walk through?